# Как экранировать js код внутри php

Tags: php, javascript, экранирование

**Есть php код и встроенный в него скрипт:**

```
<?
echo "<a type='submit' class='btn' onclick='$('#example". $order_item['id_custom_item'] ."d').popover('hide');'>Отмена</a>"  ?>
```

**На итог выдаёт на страницу следующее:**

```
<a type="submit" class="btn" onclick="$(" #example9d').popover('hide');'="">Отмена</a>
```

Получить желаемое, 2 часа пытался - не получается. **Помогите**, ... как получить, такой код:

```
<a type="submit" class="btn" onclick="$('#example9d').popover('hide');">Отмена</a>
```

**В конструкции выглядит так:**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-small  popup-marker" id="example<?= $order_item['id_custom_item'] ?>d"rel="popover" data-content="
    <?php 
         echo "<form method='post' action='../admin/post_del_item.php'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id_custom' value='$zakaz'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id_product' value='". $order_item['id_product']."'>
      <div class='control-group'>
        <div class='controls'>
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger'>Да, удалить</button>
          <a type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\" onclick=\"$('#example". $order_item['id_custom_item'] ."d').popover('hide');\">Отмена</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>";

        ?> 
        " data-original-title="Удалить позицию из заказа?"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
echo "<a type=\"submit\" class=\"btn\" onclick=\"$('#example". $order_item['id_custom_item'] ."d').popover('hide');\">Отмена</a>" 
?>
```

Comment: В таком виде работает безупречно, Вот только вставляю в конструкцию и снова "головная боль". Как проэкранировать, ни чего не получается.